# How to set site domain without Django sites framework in place?

Tags: python, django, django-sites, django-1.6

I'm moving my site from Django 1.5.x to Django 1.6.0, and I noted this in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#simplified-default-project-and-app-templates):

> [..] The admin is now enabled by default in new projects; the sites
>   framework no longer is. [..]

How to set the default domain (instead of `www.example.com`) without the Django sites framework?

Are any [`sites` related settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#sites) now made redundant redundant by this change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

- Define the domain name as a constant in your settings and use it where needed in your code. If you have only one site this is a reasonable decision as you no longer need the whole `sites` framework.
- Enable the `sites` framework again and define one `Site` object with `www.example.com` as domain. You'll also need to specify the site's id as `SITE_ID` in your Django settings.

Comment: Nice answer..  I would go with option 2, as `Sites` could be handy in multiple ways.

Comment: Oh ok, I assumed that Django would provide some setting itself... but doesn't make much difference to define it myself in the settings. @karthikr I will go for option 2 since it's an already running website with the `sites` framework in place.